# Ajax refresh generated backend image

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I am working on an image generator. The user should be able to insert some variables (such as name etc.) and submit the form with a button.
The backend generates the image and shows in the frontend. This should be happen with Ajax since I do not want to reload the page. Otherwise all the user inputs are gone, and the user needs to fill out all the fields again.

This code below works so far. There is just one problem. After the img is created and shown in the frontend (works perfectly) it does not generate new images when new input is inserted.

It should be able to replace the img with the new generated (with new inputs). The image is generated successfully in the backend.

This is my Django view:

```
def build(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        createIMG(name)
        
        context = {'msg': 'Success'}

        return JsonResponse(context)



def createIMG(name):
    current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

    template = get_template(f'src.tex')
    ...
    ...
    img1.save(f'{current_path}/media/img.png')
```

And this is my html file

```
<form method="POST" id="form-create">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Create IMG</button>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
</form>

<h4></h4>
<div class="out-img"></div>
```

This is my Script

```
<script>
$(document).on('submit', '#form-create', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{% url 'creator:build' %}",
        data: {
            name:$('#name').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        },
        success: function (data){
            if (data.msg === "Success") {
                $('h4').html('It worked!');
            }

            if (data.msg === 'Success') {
                var loadIMG = '<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/img.png" alt="">'
                jQuery('.out-img').html(loadIMG);
            }
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What is the name of the newly generated image? If it differs from `img.png`, then of course it will never show up on your client side, since you hard-coded the name of the image in your js. The better approach would be if the `build` view returned the name of the newly generated image, so that you could use it in the `img` tag

Comment: The image has still the same name. Sounds like a plan to send the name of the images. I am struggling with the JS part of it. I am pretty new and do not know how to get the name from the backend. I have the feeling the `$.ajax({})` part does not execute a second time

Comment: Could you please share your function `createIMG()` ?

Comment: I added the `createIMG()` function.
The weird thing is that the images gets generated. I can open it. But it just does not show on the frontend in the html..

Comment: you can return the image's name from `createIMG()` and pass it in the `JsonResponse context `.After that you can get the image name in the template.if you have question let me know.

Comment: And also you have to make that every image from name ,has it owns name.

Comment: can you please elaborate on how getting the 'string' I passed in the context.

Comment: example you have this in your views `context = {'msg': 'Success','image_name':'the image name'}` then in your js code you can just use `data.image_name`.

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow : Thanks a lot!!! It worked now. I use the time of creating the image. I guess it did not work because of the cacheing. You might also write a solution to the problem for other people.

Comment: I am happy , i was abble to help you.happy coding )